# How to check if both are not equal in if statement?

Tags: if-statement

I have so many of these in my code:

```
if ( x1 == x2 && y1 == y2) {
    // do nothing
}
else {
    // do the thing
}
```

I wonder if I can replace it with just if, without else, to make the code cleaner. I tried the following:

```
if ( x1 != x2 && y1 != y2) {
    // do the thing
}
```

but it doesn't work because if only one of them is not equal, then the whole thing is false.

Comment: Have you tried to use this one?:

if (x1 != x2) && (y1 != y2) {
    // do the thing
}

Comment: @BlitzNinja29: since relational operators have a higher precedence than logical comparisons, the presence of parentheses will have no effect here.

Comment: Hi @paxdiablo, thank you for clarifying me this one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of De Morgan's laws<sup>(a)</sup>:

```
not (A and B) = (not A) or (not B)
```

In other words:

```
if (x1 != x2 || y1 != y2) {
    // do the thing
}
```

If you don't want to think too much about propositional logic, you can just use the following English variant.

1. You want to *not* do "the thing" *only* if both statements are true.
2. Therefore, if *either or both* statements are false, you should do "the thing".

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The other one is:

```
not (A or B) = (not A) and (not B)
```

Comment: I had a strong intuition there was something like that, which I'd have a hard time figuring out without a formal education in computer science. Thank you!

Comment: Or, if you hate to learn mathematical logic you could write the simple NOT before your condition `if(!(x1 == x2 && y1 == y2)) //do smth`

Comment: @ArthurTarasov there's nothing CS-y here, it's what you'd say in English (or whatever language) as well: if it's not this or that, do something.

Comment: @zlakad actually I love learning math logic, I just totally missed this one. Look at that: [De Morgan's Laws](https://brilliant.org/wiki/de-morgans-laws/)! Say, could anyone point me towards a book title where I can look up other stuff like that? It's tough for me to search for things when I don't know what they are called.

Comment: @ArthurTarasov, do a search for `boolean algebra`, that should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If your code going to end in the if or else statement then you can do

```
if (x1 == x2 && y1 == y2) {
        // do something 
        return;    // this will end the execution here. 
}
// the else block would be in the rest of execution.
```

*This method is helpful when you're trying to commit certain input from user or making an assertion. So i you got the the right input continue execution else aport.. instead of checking uncertain possibilities.*